# Validate repository state after producing request to Kafka test container

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, testcontainers

I am creating an integration test with Kafka and Postgres test containers, such as:

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBootTest
@Testcontainers
@EnableKafka
@ContextConfiguration(
    initializers = {MyContainersInitializer.class} //test containers are initialized here
)
class MyIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    @MethodSource("testCases")
    @ParameterizedTest(name = "#{index} {0}")
    public void myTest(MyTestcase myTestcase) {
        
        kafkaTemplate.send(
            env.getProperty(KEY_TOPIC),
            myTestcase.input()
        );

        //... backoff ...

        assertEquals(myTestcase.expected(), myRepository.findById(myTestcase.input().getId());

    }
```

I've confirmed that everything is processed correctly, i.e. the request is received by Kafka and is processed asynchronously by the application and inserted in the database. However the test is unable to see those changes in its final step, even if I add a backoff period.

I've noticed that if a `@Transactional` annotation is added to the application service it does the trick, unfortunately I am not allowed to do it (I don't have ownership), hence I was wondering if there is another way?

Thank you for your attention

Comment: This does not seem to be an issue with the test, but with the actual application behavior?

Comment: Not sure, the application works fine when tested manually

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against using `@Transactional` to solve this issue.

As the kafka data will be received in a different thread (possibly), you are better off testing that the message is received in one test and then testing if the receiving method itself saves the data in another test.

I would bet that the async nature of this will make the use of `@Transactional` a flaky test if you plan on doing just one test.

You can also use a Mockito `verify` to see if the desired function has been called.